# Get output from database on server, but not on php script

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, limit

I have an very nasty issue....

My usage for this code: I wanna get through AJAX, just 5 records everytime i click on the further-button. I´m not so far yet....

This script just have to get me 5 records from a specific user.

**The Problem:**

So the sql queries run without any problems on the Database. But when i wanna  do it in PHP-script, i get ONLY from the first query the counter() AND the second query gives me an empty array from the PDO-Statement.

**CODE:**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['counter']) || ($_SESSION['counter'] < 0)) {

      $sql = 'SELECT count(record.record_id) AS counter FROM record 
              LEFT JOIN recordbook ON record.record_id = recordbook.record 
              WHERE user = ?';

              $sth = $this->dbc->prepare($sql);
              $sth->execute(array($u_id['user_id']));
              $count = $sth->fetch();

              $_SESSION['counter'] = $count['counter'];
              var_dump($_SESSION);
          }
          $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] - 5;

          $sql = 'SELECT record.record_id, status, place, record.record AS records, comment, recorddate 
                  FROM record LEFT JOIN recordbook ON record.record_id = recordbook.record 
                  WHERE user = ? ORDER BY record.record_id DESC LIMIT ?,5';
          $sth = $this->dbc->prepare($sql);  
          $sth->execute(array($u_id['user_id'],
                                $_SESSION['counter']));

          $output = $sth->fetchAll();
}
```

HOPE someone know how to solve this...

**table structure**

```
Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra
record_id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI NULL | auto_increment
status | varchar(200) | YES | NULL | 
place | varchar(200) | YES | NULL 
record | longtext | YES NULL 
comment | longtext | YES | NULL 
recorddate | timestamp | YES | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
attachment_id | int(10) unsigned | YES | MUL | NULL
```

Comment: Where do you loop through your fetch?

Comment: Why are you doing DESC LIMIT ?,5 if you want 5 records drop the ?,    and where's your loop?

Comment: replace `$output = $sth->fetchAll();` with `while($data=$sth->fetch()){var_dump($data);}` and see if your data is there.

Comment: need to order that cause i wanna get the last record on first position, but just only every 5 records

Comment: replaced the code and got `NULL`

Comment: Can post isolated structure of your table schema?

Comment: Check how many records are returned by your query. It it's less than 5 than statement `$_Session['counter'] = $_Session['counter'] - 5;` will result in negative counter value which is invalid as Limit offset parameter. This might be the issue. As rest of code seems fine to me.

Comment: yeah but everytime the integer gets negative, the first query is setting the counter on 12 again, cause there are 12 records from that one user:

`if (empty($_SESSION['counter']) || ($_SESSION['counter'] < 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, done! No error....

need to bind the variables to the query. Seems so, that only with prepare and execute, is it not clear enough. So add bindParam(for integer) or bindValue(for Strings) to code, than it goes nice and smoothly :)

Have seen that on PHP.net and with `debugDumpParams()` on PDOStatement you can see, how your Query is working with the Params you setted.

Here the manual http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php